# How can i loop object in useEffect React js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, put, use-effect

Here is my code! I want loop object in useEffect! I have a task to edit data! so for that I created a state and using useEffect I am taking data and showing values on input fields! but data I want to show that is images!

```
  const editor = useRef(null);
  const [content, setContent] = useState('');
  const [baseImage, setBaseImage] = useState('');
  const [baseImages, setBaseImages] = useState([]);

  // console.log('multiple images', baseImages);

  const [titleValue, setTitleValue] = useState('');
  console.log('title', titleValue);
  const [shortDesc, setShortDesc] = useState('');
  const [getCategory, setGetCategory] = useState([]);
  const [getSubCategory, setSubGetCategory] = useState([]);
  const [editValues, setEditValues] = useState([]);


useEffect(() => {
    const fetchData = async () => {
      try {
        const res = await axios.get(
          `${process.env.REACT_APP_API_URL}/article/${resultsId}`
        );
        setEditValues(res.data);
        setTitleValue(res.data.article.title);
        setShortDesc(res.data.article.shortDesc);
        setContent(res.data.article.content);
        setGetCategoryId(res.data.article.category_id);
        setGetSubCategoryId(res.data.article.subCategory_id);
        setBaseImage(
          `${process.env.REACT_APP_API_URL}` + res.data.article.image
        );
        // setBaseImages(res.data.slider);

        // for (let slide in setBaseImages(res.data.slider)) {
        //   `${process.env.REACT_APP_API_URL}` + slide.image;
        // }

     
      } catch (err) {}
    };
    fetchData();
  }, [resultsId]);
```

and here is the JSON that I am taking! Here I need to loop these sliders and put them on setBaseImages value! and afterward, display them on the input field for editing their data!

```
{article: {…}, slider: {…}}
article: {publication: "2021-04-28T17:47:18.605Z", rating: 0, _id: "60899fd57d49581056094f91", title: "chax ", author_id: "60749394a467242d21282700", …}
slider:
60899fd57d49581056094f92: {_id: "60899fd57d49581056094f92", image: "/uploads/slider/1619632085654.jpeg", article: "60899fd57d49581056094f91", __v: 0}
60899fd57d49581056094f93: {_id: "60899fd57d49581056094f93", image: "/uploads/slider/1619632085669.jpeg", article: "60899fd57d49581056094f91", __v: 0}
60899fd57d49581056094f94: {_id: "60899fd57d49581056094f94", image: "/uploads/slider/1619632085696.jpeg", article: "60899fd57d49581056094f91", __v: 0}
60899fd57d49581056094f95: {_id: "60899fd57d49581056094f95", image: "/uploads/slider/1619632085756.jpeg", article: "60899fd57d49581056094f91", __v: 0}
```

here is the input field:

```
 <input
            type='file'
            onChange={(e) => {
              uploadImages(e);
            }}
            multiple
          />
```

Comment: ```UseEffect``` is not used for looping, its basically used for initialising your variables or objects

Comment: so how take that slider?

Comment: just do `setData(res.data)`.  that's it. If you need to deal with array, go search `Javascript array` over internet. The main thing is that not every property needs to be modelled separately. Just do one property.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What's the problem? You can just run a normal loop in `useEffect` - There's nothing different about looping in that hook that's different from normal JS.

It looks like the only thing you're doing wrong is just setting a value and not doing anything with it.

`${process.env.REACT_APP_API_URL} + res.data.article.image` just concatenates two strings, does nothing with it, and then throws it away when you leave the loop. Do you want to maybe `push` something into an array?

```js
const res = {
    article: {},
    slider: [
        {"60899fd57d49581056094f92": {_id: "60899fd57d49581056094f92", image: "/uploads/slider/1619632085654.jpeg", article: "60899fd57d49581056094f91", __v: 0}},
        {"60899fd57d49581056094f93": {_id: "60899fd57d49581056094f93", image: "/uploads/slider/1619632085669.jpeg", article: "60899fd57d49581056094f91", __v: 0}},
        {"60899fd57d49581056094f94": {_id: "60899fd57d49581056094f94", image: "/uploads/slider/1619632085696.jpeg", article: "60899fd57d49581056094f91", __v: 0}},
        {"60899fd57d49581056094f95": {_id: "60899fd57d49581056094f95", image: "/uploads/slider/1619632085756.jpeg", article: "60899fd57d49581056094f91", __v: 0}}
    ]
}

for (slide of res.slider) {
  let key = Object.keys(slide)[0]
  console.log(slide[key].image);
}
```

Comment: yes, but I got an error! that JSON is from chrome console! and when I do the loop in use Effect I have an error like this... 'Line 70:11:  Expected an assignment or function call and instead saw an expression  no-unused-expressions
'

Comment: It's not because you're looping, as I said in my answer - you are not assigning the value to anything. The issue is exactly what your error describes. Try assigning your string to a variable, or better yet, pushing it to an array or something. Inside your for loop just do this `let test = process.env.REACT_APP_API_URL + slide.image;`